# lat long varies frequently

Tags: android

i am developing an application which find current latitude and longitude.but this latitude and longitude is varying frequently while my device is static.how i can remove this issue?

Comment: GPS is not perfect. You have to live with slight variations.

Comment: Furthermore, the variation in location gives you information about the quality of the positioning and you may want to use this in your application.

Comment: How much does it vary? If it's on the scale of a few meters/tens of feet, that is normal measuring error for GPS. If it's hundreds of meters or more, you may have a problem with the GPS receiver hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you can. GPS will always include a certain margin of error, you might use CellID's and maybe even WIFI networks with the GPS so that you can obtain a more exact position, how ever, there will be always be a margin of error of about 5-50 metres.